# Display page when no querystring is present

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

I have a page which requires me to have a gameweek id on page load to run specific methods.

This is parsed via the query string, and retrieved with the following:

```
gameweekID = Request.QueryString["gameweekID"];
```

For example:

```
page1.aspx?gameweekID=1
```

My issue is however on occasions where the url is page1.aspx, where no querystring is provided.

How can I default the page to gameweekID = 1, instead of getting the error

`Procedure or function 'GetPredictions' expects parameter '@gameweekID', which was not supplied.`

Comment: How are you accessing your database for your code? For example, SqlDataSource, ADO.Net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
gameweekID = Request.QueryString["gameweekID"] ?? "1";
```

Which means that if `Request.QueryString["gameweekID"]` is `null` use `"1"` instead, but this will still produce errors if you request `page1.aspx?gameweekID=` or `page1.aspx?gameweekID=foo`.

Perhaps a more elegant way would be to validate that `gameweekID` is actually an integer. Like this:

```
string gameweekIDString = Request.QueryString["gameweekID"];
int gameweekID;
if (!int.TryParse(gameweekIDString, out gameweekID))
{
    gameweekID = 1;
}
```

Comment: string gameweekIDString = Request.QueryString["gameweekID"]; this will through a object reference not set to null exception when querystring doesn't have any parameter, best way is to validate them first (if Request.QueryString["gameweekID"] != null &&  Request.QueryString["gameweekID"].value != "")

Comment: @VishalSachdeva `string gameweekIDString = Request.QueryString["gameweekID"]` will not throw an exception. Also, I'm validating the string just fine with `int.TryParse` it will return `false` if the input string is `null` or empty or not parseable. (I did remove the unnecessary `null` check from my answer, though)

Answer (score 0):

`if(Request.Querystring["gameweekID"] === null) Response.Redirect("page.aspx?!gameweekID=1")`